# ASP.NET MVC ajax jquery preloader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

so I know you could use show() and hide() of jquery during onbegin and oncomplete events of ajax calls to approach the ajax preloader effect.

What I want to know is is there a way to do it across the board? instead of manually going to each ajax form and adding onbegin and oncomplete functions etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and [jQuery.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) events: they allow you to specify the common handler for all AJAX requests.